# How to make a membership renewal form pre-filled with last year's values?

Tags: civimember, contribution-page, invoice

I'm looking for some implementation advice (using Joomla 3.4 and CiviCRM 4.6.9).

A client has a price set in place for membership that includes several standard membership levels, plus a few extra optional add-on services members can select. That works well for signups. But for renewals we'd like to be able to remind them what they paid the previous year, which they could then update or accept as given.

My first thoughts on how to do this:

1. Have a membership renewal page that pre-fills and pre-selects values based on the selections they made the previous year? I don't see a way to set up a membership contribution page in such a way that would do this (can't call up contribution info in a profile for the contribution page?). Could I do this with a hook (which one?)? Or would I need to use the API?
2. I know 4.6.9 has new invoicing capabilities, could that be used in some way to pre-set the contribution form selection? Or could I set up a process flow whereby we manually create the invoice based on values from last year, and send them an invoice that has a link to a contribution page where they can pay the amount due shown on the invoice?

Any advice would be appreciated -- anyone implemented anything like this before?

Answer (score 1):

I am not commenting on the key part of your question (too late at night) but just want to be sure that you are aware of ability to send out 'checksum' in your reminder emails, so when the link is clicked by the renewing member they arrive at a Contribution/membership page and the user is temporarily logged in so the form pre-fills. That way the system knows who they are and will treat them as an existing member who is trying to renew. It won't, afaik, show how much they paid last time, but it will default to their existing Membership Type - which might be the same thing depending on how you set up your Price Set and Membership Types. Good luck

Comment: Thanks -- I wasn't aware that I the checksum feature worked in reminder emails, that's great info. I'll look into reminder email templates and see if I can manipulate them into fulfilling my requirements.

Comment: My problem at the moment is that the renewal contribution page does not pre-select the items they paid for last time, that's the problem I'm trying to solve.  For example, we only have one type of membership with different fee levels. So the fee level they paid last time is not pre-selected on the form.  Also, there are several optional services that people can choose to pay for on a year-by-year basis, and these are also not pre-checked in the standard renewal form.

Comment: Hi - yeah that is why i wasn't really trying to answer your main point, as i don't think it is possible. Is there anyway you can rejig your approach so it has a number of Membership Types rather than offering various price levels?

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to make membership renewal

you can include membership sign up in Contribution page please refer to the document below - Try this first and if you are not sure please let me know

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Configure+Online+Contribution+Pages+for+Membership+Signup+and+Renewal

Question: are you going to make renewal manually or user will sign up manually

For Invoice : once you manage to create the above profile you can renew membership with pay later option which will create an invoice attached to contribution which you can send in Post or Email and once you receive the payment you can update the contribution to completed

Comment: I am aware I can use a Contribution page for membership renewal, that's what the system does now.

Comment: Answering your question: I would prefer that the user sign ups are done manually in the backend, and the users do the renewals themselves via the contribution page -- but would be willing to do more manual backend work if that solves my problem.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I want returning members to be able to see exactly what options they selected/ticked last year, so they can either accept that or change it, and then the contribution page recalculates the new amount due.

Comment: You can do this by setting price set for each membership and you can use buildform hook to select all the price set for that membership and select the member - previous year value - I guess its bit tricky